# Why don't I get any output?

Tags: c++, class, methods, output

I am trying to write my first OOP code in C++, but for some reason I am not getting any output. I am trying to create a class that contain a method getSquare() that accept an int n and returns the number squared. Can anyone tell me where I am doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class myClass {

public:
    int square;    
    void getSqure(int n);  
};

void myClass::getSqure(int n) {
    int square = n * n;
}

int main(){
    int n = 5;
    myClass c;

    c.getSqure(5);

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are bot outputting anything except an end of line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getSquare` function doesn't do anything, but just defines the variable `square` (does not return it though). Make it return it as an `int`, like

```
int myClass::getSqure(int n) { // make sure to change the declaration also
    int square = n * n;
    return square;
}
```

then do

```
cout << c.getSquare(5) << endl;
```

and you'll have an output.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Well, I tried that before but when I try to return the square it won't compile!!

Comment: @Zzhh82 Because your function is declared to return `void`. @vsoftco changed the function to return `int`.

Comment: @Zzhh82 did you also change the declaration to `int getSquare(int n);` inside your class?

Comment: That was the problem, I had not changed it in my class!!! It works now! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I interpreted the code while trying to stay as close as I could to the original rules of your question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    class MyClass
    {
    public:

           int Number;
           int Square;
    };

    MyClass N;

    std::cout << "Please enter a number." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> N.Number;
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Original number: " << N.Number;
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    N.Square = (N.Number * N.Number);

    std::cout << "Squared number: " << N.Square;
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Press any key to continue.";

    _getch();
    return(0);
}
```

Output:

> Please enter a number.
>   5
>
> Original number: 5
>
> Squared number: 25
>
> Press any key to continue.